# Find the value of the integral $\int_0 ^\sqrt2 \sqrt{4-x^2} \ dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

Find the value of the integral $\int_0 ^\sqrt2 \sqrt{4-x^2} \ dx$

I was unsure how to do this question so I looked at the mark scheme, and it said use $x=2\sin\theta$ and so $dx=2\cos\theta \ d\theta$

Firstly, how do you know you need to use this substitution? What do you need to look out for?

I tried doing a bit more and got $\int_0 ^{\pi/4} \sqrt{4-4\sin^2 \theta}$ which I changed into $\sqrt{4-4+\cos^2 \theta}$ using the Pythagorean identity. The markscheme however then has $\int 2\cos\theta \times 2\cos\theta$. I am not sure where they got the first 2 from, but I know the second one is from the substitution

edit: I see the problem now, really careless algebraic mistake...

Comment: remeber that you have  $\sqrt{ 4-4\sin^2 \theta}$ , which is equal to  $\sqrt{ 4-4+4\cos^2 \theta}= 2\cos \theta $

Comment: It is really important that you know your trigonometric identities really well. First know that $\sin^2(x) + \cos^2(x) = 1$, also know $1 + \tan^2(x) = \sec^2(x)$ and know some double and half angle formulas as they may help as well. You will be involved with a lot of integrals that require trigonometric substitutions so you need to get a good handle on them. These questions tends to be a lot easier when you can recall them quickly!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your problem is where you changed $(4-4\sin^2\theta)$ to $(4-4+\cos^2\theta)$. You should be changing it to $4(1-\sin^2\theta)=4(\cos^2\theta)$. The reason they know to use that substitution is because it's exactly the coefficient (2) squared that will match with the 4 to factor out, leaving you with $1-\sin^2\theta=\cos^2\theta$. Then you'll have

$\int_0^\sqrt2 \sqrt{4\cos^2\theta}(2\cos\theta d\theta)$

$ = \int_0^\sqrt2 (2\cos\theta\times 2\cos\theta)\:d\theta$

$ =\int_0^\sqrt2 4\cos^2\theta \:d\theta$

Comment: I did notice that there was a square in the square root, if I see something like that from now on will I have to use a similar substitution? I'm just wondering because I have never been taught how to handle a question like this before, and this came up in a past paper.

Comment: yeah that type of substitution is extremely common and also extremely useful.

Answer (score 2):

if you interpret the integral $ \int_0^{\sqrt2}\sqrt{4-x^2}\, dx$ as the area of the region in the first quadrant bounded by $x = 0, y=0, x = \sqrt 2$ and $y^2+x^2 = 4,$  then the area is the sum of an isosceles right ange triangle with base $\sqrt 2$ and an eighth of a circular sector of radius. therefore $$ \int_0^{\sqrt2}\sqrt{4-x^2}\, dx = \frac 12 \sqrt 2 \sqrt 2 + \frac 18 \pi( 2)^2 = 1+\frac {\pi}2.$$

Answer (score 1):

What is $4-4+\cos^2x$? It is $\cos x$. 
$\cos^2x=\frac{cos 2x+1}{2}$

Answer (score 1):

$$\sqrt{4-4 \sin^2\theta} = \sqrt{4 (1-\sin^2\theta)} = \sqrt{4 \cos^2\theta} = 2\cos\theta$$

Hence you get it as the above by using the substitution also.
Then use double angles formula to proceed. You shall get $2(\frac{1}{2}\sin 2\theta + \theta)$.

From the substitution, $x = \sin\theta$, you get $\cos\theta = \sqrt{1-x^2}$, hence $\sin 2\theta = x\sqrt{1-x^2}$.

Proceed further to get integral in terms of $x$.